# microsoft Graph API for creating online meeting giving error "UnknownError" response 404

Tags: request, microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-404, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create Online Meeting using Microsoft graph API with reference to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I am getting a response of 404 from the request.

My API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/vrund@microsoft.com/onlineMeetings/

This is my request in python which giving this error.

```
self.headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.token)
            }

response = requests.request("POST", url=API, data=body_json, headers=self.headers)
```

<Response [404]>

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-04-20T10:19:06",
      "request-id": "a82b1c87-7d3c-4006-8605-4f285068fb57",
      "client-request-id": "a82b1c87-7d3c-4006-8605-4f285068fb57"
    }
  }
}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG84r.png)

Comment: Are you using App context or User context flow? How are you getting the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
POST /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings
```

`userId` is the object ID of a user. You can't use the `userPrincipalName` here.

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request).

[image]

Please note that if you are using Application token (Application permission), don't forget to [create an application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy).

If `userPrincipalName` is supported in an endpoint, the document generally states it like this:

[image]

Comment: I have given permissions of onlineMeeting which needs but still giving this error

<Response [403]> {
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Application does not have permission to Create online meeting on behalf of this user.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-04-21T07:28:36",
      "request-id": "06929bb7-5364-461f-848c-08eff52c696b",
      "client-request-id": "06929bb7-5364-461f-848c-08eff52c696b"
    }
  }
}

Comment: @vrund297 Make sure that you add `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All` **Application permission** and [create an application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy).

Comment: OnlineMeetings.Read
Delegated

OnlineMeetings.Read.All
Application

OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite
Delegated

OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All
Application

Comment: @vrund297 Then the issue is you didn't create an application access policy. See the link I shared above.

Comment: How can i change access policy or create one. i refer that document but not able to get it.

Comment: @vrund297 Can you provide details? In which step you get an error?

Comment: I am not able to create an access policy. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy

Comment: @vrund297 What have you tried? Which steps in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy#configure-application-access-policy? And what error do you get? It lists all the steps you need to do. If you don't provide me with any details, I can't resolve it for you.